# Specify Bounded Type Parameter containing an annotation during compile time?

Tags: java, generics, compilation, annotations

**Can I check if a class contains a specific annotation during compile time if using generics?**

I'm creating a wrapper class that will be the response to various HTTP calls.

What I want is for this wrapper class to allow the user to pass in an object of any type that is annotated with my own annotation.

For example, my wrapper class can be as follows:

```
public class HTTPResponse<T> {

    private HttpStatus status;
    private int statusCode;
    private T data;

    public HTTPResponse(HttpStatus status, T data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.statusCode = status.value();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    //other getters/setters

}
```

When using this class, I can create a new HTTPResponse object and declare the type of the 'data' field:

```
HTTPResponse<SomePOJO> response = new HTTPResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK, new SomePOJO());
```

The idea is that anybody trying to use this class can pass in their own custom POJO during construction. However, I would like to be able to check that the object being passed in during construction is annotated with a custom interface created by me.

For example, my SomePOJO class **needs** to look like below:

```
@MyCustomInterface
public class SomePOJO() {
    //code stuff here
}
```

Is there a way to check that the SomePOJO class is annotated with @MyCustomInterface during compile time?

I know that I can mark my annotation so that it will be available at runtime and then perform the check in the constructor of HTTPResponse class. But I would really like for the user of my class to know as soon as possible (during compile time) that they haven't yet marked their POJO with the correct interface and thus needs to do that before creating an HTTPResponse object.

Is an annotation even the right way to go in this case? Is it 100% impossible to check for class annotation during compile time somehow and I should force users to implement my custom interface then specify

```
HTTPResponse with public class HttpResponse<T implements MyCustomInterface> {
    //fields, getters, setters
}
```

Thanks for reading if you managed to make it this far down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of my custom annotation above was to just mark a class as an item that can be used in the HTTPResponse class. The difficult part was validating this during *compile time*.

The simple answer to this issue is to **use Marker Interfaces**!

In Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, he writes:

> Marker interfaces have two advantages over marker annotations. First
>   and foremost, marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by
>   instances of the marked class; marker annotations do not. The
>   existence of this type allows you to catch errors at compile time that
>   you couldn't catch until runtime if you used a marker annotation.

Thus, the question I was asking above is invalid. You shouldn't be using marker annotations if you did want to catch errors at compile time. After changing my custom annotation to an interface, I specified my bounded generics class as follows:

```
HTTPResponse with public class HttpResponse<T implements MyCustomInterface> {
    //fields, getters, setters
}
```